# Any API to install chrome extension crx programatically

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Are there any API to install downloaded Chrome .crx extensions programatically using Java.
I googled a lot but I did not find any API through which I can call it in my program and get my work done.
I got various manual methods like using policy or Adding to Windows registry etc....

Can somebody tell me how can I achieve this task programatically

Comment: [Java](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) or [JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)? With user interaction, using JavaScript: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webstore.html#method-install